# Confusion on the definition of $G_{\delta}$ sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm confused on the definition of $G_{\delta}$ sets. Firstly let me state the definition I understand: Let $E$ be a set in suitable topological space. $E$  is called a $G_{\delta}$ set if $E$ can be written as a countable intersections of open sets.

So any open set $U$ is $G_{\delta}$ set, since it is the "union" of one set, $U$ itself. And on the other hand, any $G_{\delta}$ set is open, by the topological knowledge.

So "open sets" are equivalently to "$G_{\delta}$ sets"? Weird.. So why do we need a new terminology?

Comment: You switch from intersection in the definition, to union in your analysis.  If a "$G_\sigma$ set" is defined as a countable **union** of open sets, then, as you proved here, that is the same thing as an open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, consider the standard topology on $\mathbb R$, and let $U_n=(-\frac1n,\frac1n)$. $$\bigcap\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}U_n=\{0\}$$So, $\{0\}$ is a $G_\delta$ set in the standard topology, while clearly not being open.

More generally, countable intersections of open sets aren't guaranteed to be open by the axioms of a topology. You seem to have confused **union** with **intersection**.

Answer (score 2):

Countable intersection of open sets is not open. And a $G_{\delta}$ is a countable intersection of open sets.

Any open subset $U$ of a topolgical space $X$ is $G_{\delta}$ because you can consider $U=\bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i$ where $X_0=U$ and $X_i=X$ for all $i>0$.

Comment: OP already knows that all open sets are $G_\delta$.

Comment: Check what @GEdagar has written.

Comment: Other than confusing intersection with union, I don't see anything wrong with what OP has done.